# How To Set up Custom Cron Job in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-cron, cronjobs

Can anyone explain the methods to doing this job done?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create your cron in `Cron` directory

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Cron/Mycron.php

<?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;
     
    class Mycron
    {
        protected $logger;
     
        public function __construct(
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface
        ) {
            $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
        }
     
        public function execute() {
            //Code here
            //$this->logger->debug('Vendor\Module\Cron\Mycron');
    
        }
    }
```

then create cron_groups.xml in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/cron_groups.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="vendor_module_cron_group">
        <schedule_generate_every>1</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>4</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>2</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
        <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
    </group>
</config>
```

This will add entry in admin

Now for scheduling create crontab.xml in `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/crontab.xml`. Schedule it according to your need

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="vendor_module_cron_group">
    
        <job name="vendor_module_cronjob_mycron" instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\Mycron" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
         
    </group>
</config>
```

This will run your cron every 5 min. your magento cron must be configured on your server or you can run manually by running `php bin/magento cron:run` (run twice for schedule and execute)

Note: you can skip cron_groups.xml step and define default group too as below

```
<group id="default">
```